# Sculpt not showing in Object mode

Tags: sculpting, object-mode

I Have been Working on a Photoscan and am trying to clean it up in Sculpt mode. When I Switch back to Object Mode all my changes are lost, everything I did in Sculpt mode are all gone.

---

For example this is what it looks like in Sculpt mode:

[image]

But when I switch to object mode it looks like this
[image]

Here are the wire frame picture in edit mode
enter image description here
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What modifiers (if any) does your object have? Are you using a multiresolution modifier?

Comment: No i just imported it in and Started Sculpting as that was what i saw both Peter France and CGGeek Do in both their Youtube Videos on Photoscanning

Comment: Please add an image to your question of the wireframe of the object in edit mode.

Comment: I have updated my initial post as i did not know how to add pictures to comments

Comment: Thanks :) It's better to have all information in the question body, it helps keep the site organized and a good many users do not bother reading the comments to look for information (this is not like a forum).

Comment: This looks like a shading problem. Imported models can have custom normals. Go to the mesh properties > Geometry Data and click on "clear custom split normals" if you have the option

Comment: @Gorgious Im sorry i am not able to find "Clear Custom Split Normals" is this an add-on that i have to enable?

Comment: Nope, if you do not find it, it means there is none and this is not the problem. Just to be sure you can find the setting there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0OS9.png

Comment: @ Gorgious Thankyou it worked Thankyou Very much